# How do I get a .net standard 2.0 project to build on TFS2015

Tags: tfs, msbuild, .net-standard-2.0

I have a .net standard 2.0 class library in a .net 4.7.1 web solution.

Building the solution locally works fine, but when the TFS server builds the solution it is unable to compile the .net 2.0 standard library. It crashes during compilation and complains that system.object etc is not defined or imported.

It's a TFS 2015 running the old tfsbuild.proj style xml files.
The build server is otherwise up to date with .net 4.7.1, latest .net core 2.0.3, latest visual studio, latest build tools.

I can see that it generates a csc.exe command to compile the .net standard 2.0 project that crashes. If I simply was to run "dotnet build", it works great.

Watching the logs of the build I can see that the CoreCompile step when running in VS or "dotnet build" contains a "References" Task Parameter with references to the .net standard 2 library. This Task Parameter is missing in the CoreCompile step when the build server is running the build.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to best proceed to get msbuild on the tfs server to successfully compile the .net standard 2.0 project?

Could I get msbuild to generate the necessary "References" task parameter?

Is my best option to turn off automatic building of .net standard projects and try to do everything manually as build steps with "dotnet build" instead, since dotnet build correctly identifies the necessary references?

Comment: Which build system are you using on the TFS2015? The old XAML build or new vNext build?

Comment: @DanielMann - Every version of TFS build from inception to current uses msbuild for .net projects.

Comment: @StingyJack TFS 2008 had a build system where build definitions were simply MSBuild files that imported TFS-specific targets (for things like mapping workspaces and synchronizing source code). This is what I was referring to. The question referred to running `tfsbuild.proj` files, which was the convention that TFS 2008-style builds used. That build system has indeed been deprecated since TFS 2010 introduced XAML builds, which in turn was deprecated by the build system introduced in TFS 2015.

Comment: I recall that awfulness, but every build system for .net is going to be msbuild-centric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you are trying to use the VS2015 MSBuild tools to build a solution which includes a .NET Standard 2.0 project.

> The .NET team **changed the project file structure** (first announced
>   [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/10/19/net-core-tooling-in-visual-studio-15/)) for new .NET Core and .NET Standard projects along with the
>   release of Visual Studio 2017.

Support for building .NET Core/Standard came with the [*TFS 2017 Update 2*](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/tfs2017-update2#a-idbuild-a-build-and-release-improvements) update.

> ***.NET Core tasks support project files***
>
> *With the current update, we are enhancing .NET core tasks to support `*.csproj` files in addition to project.json. You can now use Visual
>   Studio 2017 on your build agents to build .NET core applications using
>   csproj files.*

As a workaround, you could try to give up of using the TFS 2015 build task MSBUILD and Visual Studio Build, and now use the **Command Line step**.  In general, if you can perform a task on the commandline you can also do it in TFS/VSTS. More detail steps please refer this blog: [Building .NET Core and .NET Standard Projects in TFS 2015](https://www.dotnetcatch.com/2017/11/15/building-net-core-and-net-standard-projects-in-tfs-2015/)

Comment: We are running an old tfsbuild task, and not an msbuild task. Visual Studio 2017 is no longer able to open our old buildprocesstemplate for editing without crashing. Rewriting our whole build process from the old tfsbuild.proj style is unfortunately not something I can take time to do at the moment. I did some testing and noticed that calling msbuild as you suggest would indeed work, but in the end I opted for manually calling dotnet build on the specific project as a build step instead as stepping away from the tfs solution build caused a lot of other issues or us. Marking this as answer. TY.

Answer (score 0):

Earlier this week I was able to get a class library targeting netstandard2.0+net452 to build on TFS 2015 update 4, using the vNext build system. This would probably work using the XAML builds, provided you have the ability to run either a PowerShell or batch script.

I had to do a few things not mentioned in what @PatrickLu-MSFT explains.

The key points/differences are

1. Installing update 2 for TFS 2015 was not enough. You also need the right VS components installed on the build server. I had to install/update VS 2017 Enterprise 15.6.x **and** VS 2017 Build tools 15.6.x on the build server. Both of these had all the targeting packs except for 3.5 and 4.0. Dotnet core is an important selection as that's where the SDK project support seems to come from, and you may need to use the dotnet.exe.
2. Run `dotnet restore` instead of nuget.exe (4.5) or msbuild (v15.6) to restore packages. Those two expect some JSON file and can't produce it for themselves. For me this was a two line script; one to set the location to where the solution is, and the other to call the restore.

After that it was a matter of calling the msbuild that is installed with VS 2017 as mentioned in PatrickLu's answer.

At that point the solution should compile, but if you needed to do something else with the assembly after that like make PDB's or package it, beware these potential problems...

- `nuget.exe pack` doesn't understand how to find the DLLs to make a nuget package correctly. It keeps looking in a `\release\any cpu\my.project\release\netstandard20\` output path, but that isn't defined in that project.
- VS 2017 may try to double up your output paths from `\release\netstandard20 to` release\netstandard20\netstandard20`.
- Trying to add `/t:Pack` to the existing msbuild call fails for every project in the solution that does not have a pack target, like unit tests for the assembly being packed.
- The [MSFT docs pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets) are full of general info, but missing how to add a pack target for non-SDK style projects. The prior versions of it that did cover them are missing.
- The default "portable" type debug symbols for netstandard2.0 can't be indexed by the builtin vnext build task.
- Selecting "full" debug symbol type in the project properties for all configurations isn't honored by msbuild.
- Specifing the command line options for full symbols to msbuild, does appear to make indexable symbols, but I haven't tried them to see if they work.